# C# WPF: View doesn't get the changes of property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, properties

I'm learning wpf c# about property binding. I create a simple wpf application. I try to bind the width of rectangle control to property "PageWidth" in code behind. But somehow it doesn't work (the view doesn't get the changes of the property). 
What I want to achieve: 
- the width of rectangle is initialized in code behind by 100
- if the button "width++" is clicked, the width of rectangle is increased stepwise by 10.
Do I miss something in my code? Please advice and feel free to modify my code. Thanks in advance.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle
        Fill="#FF6262BD"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="23,24,0,0"
        Stroke="Black"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="{Binding Path=PageWidth}"
        Height="100" />
    <Button
        Content="Width++"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="35,129,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="75"
        Click="Button_Click" />

</Grid>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyWpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PageWidth = 100;
        }

        private Int32 _pageWidth;
        public Int32 PageWidth
        {
            get
            {
                return _pageWidth;
            }
            set
            { 
                if ( _pageWidth != value )
                {
                     _pageWidth = value;
                }
            }
         }

         private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
             if ( PageWidth <= 200 )
             {
                  PageWidth += 10;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- you didn't set a `DataContext`, so the binding has no reference (it doesn't know from which object it should get the `PageWidth` property)
- `PageWidth` is not a dependency property and doesn't raise the `PropertyChanged` event, so there is no way to notify the binding system when the value changes.

To fix those problems, you should:

- set the DataContext to the window itself:

  ```
  // in the constructor
  DataContext = this;
  ```
- make the `MainWindow` class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and change the `PageWidth` property so that it raises the `PropertyChanged` event:

  ```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      ...

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
          var handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }

      private Int32 _pageWidth;
      public Int32 PageWidth
      {
          get
          {
              return _pageWidth;
          }
          set
          { 
              if ( _pageWidth != value )
              {
                   _pageWidth = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("PageWidth");
              }
          }
       }

       ...
  ```